# Win forms font settings

Tags: .net, vb.net, fonts, styles

i have one screenshot to show.
On the left is settings dialog from my vb.net application and on the right is Microsoft SkyDrive dialog.

http://croos.org/so.jpg

The difference is huge.
What are the fonts in the SkyDrive dialog? Buttons, labels, tabs? My program uses
Font = SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont (Segoe ui) but it's not good enough.

How can I achieve that my dialog look like one from the right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the screen shot of skydrive that you have shown is using Tahoma (or something very similar) font not Segoe UI.

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 8)
End Sub
```

Or just set the form font in the properties window.

I created a new form using the Tahoma font - this looks almost identical to me. My form on the left and your original on the right for comparison:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but I already tried that. It's not tahoma. It must be something else that I can do to achieve professional look in my apps?

Comment: @user1573412 - I think it is Tahoma - I have uploaded a sample Tahoma form

Comment: Please take look at screenshot :

http://croos.org/vs-compiled.jpg

Form in VS designer (font ok), on the right is compiled app (font not ok ) Look at radio buttons at the top.

Comment: same thing happens when I try to design new form.